# ls: cannot access /directory/path/*.rar: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, ls

From the following results it appears the *.rar is being taken literally, and not expanded.  man glob gives no detail as to how it expands.  Would someone kindly explain why?

```
~/Films $ls "Night of the Living Dead (1968)/"  
Night_of_the_Living_Dead_1968.par2        Night_of_the_Living_Dead_1968.part23.rar.1  
Night_of_the_Living_Dead_1968.part01.rar  Night_of_the_Living_Dead_1968.part24.rar  
...

~/Films $ls "Night of the Living Dead (1968)/*.rar"  
ls: cannot access Night of the Living Dead (1968)/*.rar: No such file or directory  
~/Films $ls "$(pwd)/Night of the Living Dead (1968)/*.rar"  
ls: cannot access /home/g/Films/Night of the Living Dead (1968)/*.rar: No such file or directory  
~/Films $ls "Night of the Living Dead (1968)/*rar"  
ls: cannot access Night of the Living Dead (1968)/*rar: No such file or directory
```

Comment: do ls "Night of the Living Dead (1968)"/*rar

Answer (score 4):

A `*` inside single quotes is treated literally. So you need to put only the directory name that has spaces in it, in quotes:

```
ls "Night of the Living Dead (1968)"/*.rar
```

A `*` inside double quotes is expanded by the shell.

Comment: A * inside single quotes is treated literally.  A * inside double quotes is expanded as a glob.

Comment: apologies--I was thinking the OPs issue was that ls was set to a function or an alias that was munging the quotes; but in fact it is my function that was causing "*" to expand!  I cannot remove the downvote unless you edit your answer.

Comment: An easier way to do this interactively is `ls Night[TAB]/*.rar`; let the shell complete the directory name rather than typing it out.  The shell's tab completion will insert backslashes as necessary to escape any special characters.